# MySQL query total time where a value equal to "X"

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple table, id, datetime, and status (integer).

If I insert a row the id will auto increment, the timedate is now and the status is a 1 or 0.

I'm basically inserting each time status changes between a 1 and 0.

Is it possible to do a query for total time (minutes or seconds) that the status was a 1 with the current table arrangement?

I'm not looking for someone to do work for me, but for guidance.

I have done some searching and perhaps I don't know the keywords for best results.  Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: Here is an example table with data, total time should be 660 seconds/11 minutes.

```
Id      t_stamp           Status
1   2019-05-14 17:30:00      1
2   2019-05-14 17:35:00      0
3   2019-05-14 17:40:00      1
4   2019-05-14 17:45:00      0
5   2019-05-14 17:46:00      1
6   2019-05-14 17:47:00      0
```

Here's a query that does give me the correct results.  It's a first stab, any advice on better ways to create the table, or the query?

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Stop) - TIME_TO_SEC(Start)) AS Total FROM

(SELECT id, t_stamp AS Start FROM table WHERE status = 1) A INNER 
JOIN (SELECT id, t_stamp AS Stop FROM table WHERE status = 0) B
ON A.id = B.id -1
```

Comment: Some guidance then: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Try reading the 3rd example in this link:  https://database.guide/datediff-examples-in-sql-server/

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post, any advice on what I posted?